# Starting JVM on AIX (PASE)

Tags: java

Iam attempting to start JVM from the JPYPE package on IBM I server (AIX PASE). While doing so the JVM does start but crashes soon after with bunch of unhandled exceptions and dump files. I did try to start the JVM using a C program but that too crashed with the exceptions. Is there a way to find the reasons ?, any diagnosis tools ?. The JIT dump file has the following messages:-

- INFO: Crashed in application thread 000000003000E700.
- INFO: Found 0 JITed methods on Java stack.
- INFO: DUMP FAILED: no methods to recompile

Comment: Unless I'm missing something huge, you're talking about Java virtual machine (JVM) and if that's the case, which it sounds like, this is a **Java** issue, not a Python one. So I'm re-tagging this question.

Comment: Yes its about Java Virtual machine on AIX from Python actually.